# "Expected css... to return something" : rspec fail while test by hand works (can't reproduce the fail myself)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I'm working on a training app which is an Ogame-Like game (https://github.com/arnlen/ogame-like).

I'm using rspec (with Capybara) in order to test my app.
I'm stacked for several hours because rspec is complaining for an error which **I can't reproduce ** by myself with my browser.

Here is my **rspec code** :

```
describe 'Planet pages' do

let(:user){FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
before {sign_in user}

subject {page}

describe "new planet page" do
    before {visit new_planet_path}  

    describe "with valid information" do
        before do
            visit new_planet_path
            fill_in "Name", with: "MyPlanet"
            click_button "Validate"
        end

        # This test doesn't pass
        it {should have_selector('h1', text: "Planet")}
    end
end

end
```

The failure :

```
  1) Planet pages new planet page with valid information
 Failure/Error: it {should have_selector('h1', text: "Planet")}
   expected css "h1" with text "Planet" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/planet_pages_spec.rb:34:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the involved code.

My function "**sign_in**" used by rspec *(location : spec/support/utilities.rb)*

```
def sign_in(user)
    visit signin_path

    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
end
```

My **UsersController**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
    sign_in @user
    redirect_to new_planet_path
else
    render 'new'
end
 [...]
```

My **PlanetsController**

```
class PlanetsController < ApplicationController

before_filter :signed_in_user

def index
    @planets = current_user.planets
end

def new
    @planet = Planet.new
end

def create
    @planet = Planet.new(name: params[:planet][:name],
        coordinates: generate_coordinates,
        metal_ressource: 1000,
        user_id: current_user.id)
    if @planet.save
        flash[:success] = "Welcome on your first planet!"
        redirect_to action: 'index'
    else
        flash[:error] = "Error naming your planet"
        render 'new'
    end
end
end
```

And **My Planet Index view**

```
<% @planets.each do |planet| %>
    <h1>Planet : <%= planet.name %></h1>
    <p><%= "Coordinates : #{planet.coordinates}" %></p>
<% end %>
```

I tried to user the Capybara method "**save_and_open_page**", but rspec raised an error "undefined method"

I also tried step by step debugging by iterations on my spec file, and it revealed that **the error occurs right after the "click_button 'Validate'"**. For an unknown reason, rspec seems not to be able to reach the planets_path ("index" action from PlanetsController).

I'm out, if anybody has an idea, I take it !

---

### EDIT : SOLVED - Found the problem!

Using the "**save_and_open_page**" method from Capybara, I figured out what was going on: the planet created by rspec didn't have any coordinates, which was not allowed by the model.

---

#### How to debug with the wonderful "save_and_open_page" method

1. Add this to your gemfile : "**gem 'launchy'**"
2. Install it : **bundle install**
3. Put the command "**save_and_open_page**" wherever you want

---

Hope it could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Capybara also has a `save_page` method, which is easier to use as it does not seem to need the "launchy" gem. The pages are saved in `tmp/capybara`. In the rspec tests, be sure to use `save_page` inside `before`, `it`, or some other block. It will not work as a separate command. Example:

```
    before { visit signup_path; save_page }
```